# get a different file name

Tags: java

How do i get a different file name on a webserver by requesting the url.

for example "file" click url link and  get "file.bin"

the "file" is located on a webserver by requesting the url, user can download "file.bin" instead of "file"

something like (file + .bin)

Comment: What do you mean by "a different file name"? Different from what?

Answer (score 1):

When you are sending the response from the server, you can set the content type, content disposition etc.
Set the file name in the response header as below

```
response.setContentType("application/pdf");
response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment;filename=testFile.pdf");
```

Comment: I do not understand can you make a sample please.

Comment: How are you sending the file back to the browser?
What does the link on your screen point to? an Action or The actual file?